# What is the moment of inertia of a disc about an axis through its diameter?

Tags: calculus, integration

What is the moment of inertia of a dics of mass $m$ and radius $r$ about an axis through its diameter (like when spinning a coin)?

My textbook says $$I = \int r^2\, dm = \int_{-r}^r(x^2 \rho \sqrt{r^2-x^2})\, dx$$
because $dm = \rho f(x) dx$.

It may be simple but I really don't understand how we know that $dm = \rho f(x) dx$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you take a thin area element parallel to the axis of a disk, you get something like the almost-rectangle shown in the diagram below.

[image]

If the distance from the axis to the "rectangle" is $x,$ the height of the rectangle is $2 \sqrt{r^2 - x^2}.$
The width is $\mathrm dx$, so the area is $2 \sqrt{r^2 - x^2}\, \mathrm dx.$
If $\rho$ is the mass per unit area, then the mass of the rectangle is
$2\rho \sqrt{r^2 - x^2}\, \mathrm dx.$
The moment of inertia of the rectangle around the parallel axis is therefore
$2\rho x^2 \sqrt{r^2 - x^2}\, \mathrm dx.$

For some reason, the author of the book seems to have forgotten the factor of $2$ in the height of the rectangle,
unless this is $I$ for just the top half of the disk.

Comment: That makes perfect sence, thank you. Could you give me a hint what to do with the integral too, please? I tried substitution of $x = rsin(\theta)$ but I am getting acrsin in the result, when the result should be $\frac{mr^2}{4}$

Comment: @LaurenSin After the substitution $x=r\sin\theta$ you should get something like $\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta$ to integrate. How do you get $\arcsin$ out of that?

Comment: That is true but when I integrate it I get arcsin. But I forgot to substitute back, now I got the correct result. Thanks for help.